# aapanel as mysql remote server

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I have a VPS installed with aaPanel. Does anyone knows how to access the mysql server outside the system?

something like

```
<?php
   $servername = "111.222.33.44";
   $username = "username";
   $password = "password";

   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

   if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 

I get this error

Answer (score 2):

Open port 3306 with the security button on the left side of the aaPanel interface.

Comment: Yes! I already got it thank you!